# Why is the spectrum of a blue flame the way it is?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, molecules, combustion

In the [spectrum of the blue part in a candle flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spectrum_of_blue_flame_-_intensity_corrected.png), there’s a violet emission at 432 nm due to excited CH* molecules (chemiluminescence). Why 432? Why not 400 or 500? There are emissions at 436, 475 and 520 nm too. Why these numbers? Is it because the energies of the photons emitted correspond to these wavelengths, as E = hc/λ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atoms and small molecules have discrete energetic states. When an excited molecule relaxes to the ground state by emitting a photon, the energy (wavelength) of this photon is equal to the energy difference between the 2 states.

Comment: Is the photon’s energy unequal to the energy difference between the states?

Comment: It is equal to a energy difference between two states (of the same molecule). Since small molecules have not too many states, there is only a fixed number of wavelengths they can emit at.

Comment: Your answer here is the answer to [my other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163405/why-is-the-bottom-part-of-a-candle-flame-blue) too. If you want, copy your answer and paste it to that page. I’d make it the “accepted answer.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And because those energies correspond to differences in energy between bonds in CH and C2 and bonds in the CO2 and H2O reaction products.

Comment: The wavelength of chemiluminescence is only related to energy difference between the electronically excited and the ground state of CH radical, not to the energy of other molecules and not really to bond energy.

Comment: Very true. I should have taken more time with this.